# Adding a blur onto image upon scrolling

Tags: jquery, css, scroll, blur, onscroll

i am trying to achieve a gradual addition of a filter:blur(0px) as you scroll down the page.

So as you scroll the image blur px goes up. need to do this gradually  but not sure how to achieve it via jquery. any help out there?

what i have so far is:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {

      var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
      var divam = 5;
          $(".ftimg").css({
              "background-position":"0px -"+scrollTop/divam+"px"     
          });

    });
```

this edits the background position however, im not sure how to chnage the blur. something like this doesnt work:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {

      var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
      var divam = 5;
          $(".ftimg").css({
              "filter":"blur: -"+scrollTop/divam+"px"     
          });

    });
```

Comment: can you show what you have so far

Comment: Start by looking into jQuery's .scroll() event handler https://api.jquery.com/scroll/. You can bind the event to $(window) and increment or reduce the filter:blur() value dependent on your scroll postion. You can get the position of the scroll bar by using jQuery's .scrollTop() function http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/

Comment: i am using scrolltop howveer i think my syntax is wrong

Comment: something like this http://codepen.io/andreasstorm/pen/pyjEh ?

Comment: hi @kumar not exactly. i dont want two seperate images. just one image with the filter: blur (px); to be altered as you scroll.

Comment: managed to fix it on my own:

Answer (score 0):

i managed to fix it on my own:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {

          var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
          var divam = 90;
          var blurstr = "blur("+scrollTop/divam+"px)";
              $(".cover-pic").css({
                  "-webkit-filter": blurstr,
                    "filter": blurstr   
              });

        });
```